# Linq Rankings by year c#

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

What I am attempting to accomplish here is return 1 car per year for ten years. 
what I am getting though is 10 cars that are all 2013 cars. 
This should sort by year 2013 2012 2011 etc.. It should be the car with the most recalls for that given year.

```
public static IEnumerable<MakeModel> mostrecalledmodelbyYear
{
    get
    {
        var groups = from t in DBCacheHelper.recallslist
                        where t.YEARTXT != "9999"
                        group t by new { t.YEARTXT, t.MODELTXT, t.MAKETXT } into g
                        select new MakeModel() { MODELTXT = g.Key.MODELTXT, MAKETXT = g.Key.MAKETXT, Frequency = g.Count(),YEARTXT = Convert.ToInt32(g.Key.YEARTXT) };

        return groups.OrderByDescending(g => g.YEARTXT).Take(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: the most recalls = frequency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like that

```
var query= 
(from t in DBCacheHelper.recallslist
where t.YEARTXT != "9999"
group t by t.YEARTXT into g
let q = g.GroupBy(t => new {t.MODELTXT, T.MAKETXT})
         .Select(g2 => new {
               key = g2.Key,
               freq = g2.Count()
            })
         .OrderByDescending(t => t.freq)
let max = q.FirstOrDefault()
select new MakeModel {
   MODELTXT = max.key.MODELTXT,
   MAKETXT = max.key.MAKETXT,
   Frequency = max.freq,
   YEARTXT = g.Key//care, Convert.ToInt32 won't work in linqtoentities 
})
.OrderByDescending(f => f.YEARTXT)
.Take(10);
```

Comment: one last thing you forgot on there was this right before Take(10)
.OrderByDescending(f => f.YEARTXT)